# Can I edit the Firmware for my Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, nokia-lumia-1020, windows-mobile

Apologies if the question seems terrible! But it seems possible to me, well, I'm mainly a Mechanical Engineering student.

So, First things first...I know the basics but don't know much about the core of Windows. But I'm always curious and this question here is one of the results. In high-hopes I am wondering:

1. **Can the Firmware of Windows Phones be accessed?**
2. **Can I understand its language?** (To edit parts of it)

Additionally, I am thinking of Importing USB-OTG support in FW of my phone. Because W10M as an OS supports OTG (eg: Lumia 950XL) that I knew.

Note - *"Provisional packages" can be (are) supplied to mobile devices via Removable Media Option (means: system w/o OTG-support do read flash drives)*

Note2- *Ninko in partnership with Windows provides proprietary OTG support for  Windows Phone*

Link for **Ninko App** to access OTG on Store: [Ninko+WP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/ninko-wp/9wzdncrdg98s?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab)

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, otg is just part of name for usb and no other meaning that I know of. While you can do a lot with Windows, it not the same as windows mobile. I've never heard of a way to get usb device to work with windows mobile. You see, you require a driver to talk to usbdevice. But there is no drivers for Windows mobile, unless your an oem developing Windows hardware.

Comment: As for firmware, you would have to dissassemble the device and to begin understanding the topology of the device. Maybe the spi flash which typically stores flash is not on the usb?